# is it ok to use React Router "Nested" routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i have a React app that uses React Router v5 (although i think the question applies to v4,5, and 6).

Here is what I want to do:
in App.js:

```
<Router>
   <Route path='/main' component={Main}/>
   <Route path='/admin' component={Admin}/>
</Router>
```

And then in Main.js I have 2 other routes:

```
const Main=()=> {
    
   return (
      <div className='some-special-styling-only-for-main'>
          <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
          <Route path='/calculator' component={Calculator}/>
      </div>

   )
}
```

This works, but is there anything wrong with it and is it best practice? I am asking because I notice some other Routers like react-location do not allow this (you have to define all routes in one place). Also I've never seen anyone else do it after hours of researching online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are descendent routes, not nested routes, but that doesn't matter as the question, as posed, is a bit subjective. `react-router-dom` allows it, so yes, it's ok to do. There is no issue with React components rendering descendent routes.

This is a very common routing pattern in RRDv4/5. RRDv6 allows it and made nesting routes even easier than in previous versions.

I'm not sure where exactly you were looking for examples of rendering descendent/"nested" routes and not finding any, but there's an official [Nesting Example](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) in the v5 docs.